# Supporting multiple gradle versions in single build.gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Due to build tools, my gradle file has to be compatible both with Android Gradle 2.1.3 and the latest Android Gradle version. As  the latest Android Gradle Plugin has introduced the new `implementation` and `api` configuration, and is planning to remove the `compile` configuration, I am trying to figure out a way to write script that it should bebe able to support both versions.
The idea would be to use something like

```
def _api = api
```

and in the `dependencies` use `_api` instead of `api`.

Later we plan to add add some code like;

```
if (oldVersion)
    _api = compile
```

I have tried this code as is, but it is invalid code.
Any ideas how it should be coded?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation:

```
dependencies {
    api "org.example:example:1.0"
}
```

is really syntactic sugar for

```
dependencies {
    add("api", "org.example:example:1.0")
}
```

so you could solve that problem by defining `String` variables, whose value depends on the Gradle version.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Here is the  code
`def oldGradleVerion = (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.size() > 0 && (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.get(0).contains("Release")));`
`def _api = oldGradleVerion ? "compile" : "api";`
`def _implementation = oldGradleVerion ? "compile" : "implementation";`
`def _compileOnly = oldGradleVerion ? "provided" : "compileOnly";`
`def _testImplementation = oldGradleVerion ? "testCompile" :  "testImplementation";`

`dependencies {`
`    add (_implementation, 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0')`
`}`